# Date in 1 cell - how do I count the number of dates

Tags: countif

I have dates in one cell i.e. 12/05/2023, 05/03/2023, 07/05/2023, is there a formula that I can use to count the number of dates in one cell?

Comment: Count the number of separators + 1 :-)

Comment: Thank you   =COUNTIF(A1,",") - would this be the formula?

Comment: No, that would only count 'the number of cells' (and not the number of occurrences in a cell) if the cell contains only a comma

Comment: Ahh ok - would you know what formula I would need to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

What this formula does, is counts the characters in the cell (using the `LEN` formula), then it uses `SUBSTITUTE` to replace all the commas in the cell with nothing, counts the characters now, and subtracts this from the initial count.

Note: the `+1` in the end is needed if there is no trailing comma after the last date. Remove that if there is a comma after that.

Comment: Amazing thank you - worked perfectly

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.